# Errors during compilation: AbstractConfigOption.php

Tags: magento2, php

I have just run a composer update on my Magento 2.4.2-p1 installation and now I cant compile it, I am getting the following error

```
    Errors during compilation:
        Magento\Framework\Setup\Option\AbstractConfigOption
                Incompatible argument type: Required type: int. Actual type: string; File: 
/var/www/vhosts/mydomain.co.uk/httpdocs/vendor/magento/framework/Setup/Option/AbstractConfigOption.php

Total Errors Count: 1

In Log.php line 92:
                            
  Error during compilation
```

The updated modules are

- Upgrading aws/aws-sdk-php (3.185.20 => 3.185.21)
- Upgrading mageplaza/magento-2-english-united-kingdom-language-pack (dev-master 8e27b82 => dev-master 83b40fa)
- Upgrading symfony/config (v5.3.3 => v5.3.4)
- Upgrading symfony/console (v4.4.26 => v4.4.27)
- Upgrading symfony/css-selector (v5.3.0 => v5.3.4)
- Upgrading symfony/dependency-injection (v5.3.3 => v5.3.4)
- Upgrading symfony/event-dispatcher (v4.4.25 => v4.4.27)
- Upgrading symfony/filesystem (v5.3.3 => v5.3.4)
- Upgrading symfony/finder (v5.3.0 => v5.3.4)
- Upgrading symfony/http-foundation (v5.3.3 => v5.3.4)
- Upgrading symfony/mime (v5.3.2 => v5.3.4)
- Upgrading symfony/options-resolver (v5.3.0 => v5.3.4)
- Upgrading symfony/process (v4.4.26 => v4.4.27)
- Upgrading symfony/property-access (v5.3.0 => v5.3.4)
- Upgrading symfony/property-info (v5.3.1 => v5.3.4)
- Upgrading symfony/stopwatch (v5.3.0 => v5.3.4)
- Upgrading symfony/yaml (v5.3.3 => v5.3.4)

Does anyone have an idea whats causing the error?

Answer (score 17, accepted):

Since approx. 2hrs there is a pull request for symfony/console. This will fix that issue.

https://github.com/symfony/console/pull/75

Comment: That PR is just a change to a docblock though?

Comment: Well hey what do you know, it works!

Comment: symfony/console 4.4.29 was published. This contians the fix.

Answer (score 14):

I had the same problem tonight. I did a trace to find out which module is causing the problem. I had to downgrade symfony/console to get it to compile.

```
composer require symfony/console=4.4.26
```

After you have downgraded symfony/console, you will need to run the Magento 2 upgrade script to make sure you are compiling the new module.

```
php bin/magento setup:upgrade
php bin/magento setup:di:compile
```

This is the error generated in the log when trying to compile Magento 2 using symfony/console 4.4.27...

```
Interception cache generation... 6/9 [==================>---------]  66% 31 secs 498.0 MiBErrors during compilation:
    Magento\Framework\Setup\Option\AbstractConfigOption
        Incompatible argument type: Required type: int. Actual type: string; File: 
/var/www/html/magento2/vendor/magento/framework/Setup/Option/AbstractConfigOption.php

Total Errors Count: 1

In Log.php line 92:
                                           
  [Magento\Framework\Validator\Exception]  
  Error during compilation                 
                                           

Exception trace:
  at /var/www/html/magento2/setup/src/Magento/Setup/Module/Di/Compiler/Log/Log.php:92
 Magento\Setup\Module\Di\Compiler\Log\Log->report() at /var/www/html/magento2/setup/src/Magento/Setup/Module/Di/Code/Reader/Decorator/Interceptions.php:85
 Magento\Setup\Module\Di\Code\Reader\Decorator\Interceptions->getList() at /var/www/html/magento2/setup/src/Magento/Setup/Module/Di/App/Task/Operation/InterceptionCache.php:59
 Magento\Setup\Module\Di\App\Task\Operation\InterceptionCache->doOperation() at /var/www/html/magento2/setup/src/Magento/Setup/Module/Di/App/Task/Manager.php:56
 Magento\Setup\Module\Di\App\Task\Manager->process() at /var/www/html/magento2/setup/src/Magento/Setup/Console/Command/DiCompileCommand.php:216
 Magento\Setup\Console\Command\DiCompileCommand->execute() at /var/www/html/magento2/vendor/symfony/console/Command/Command.php:255
 Symfony\Component\Console\Command\Command->run() at /var/www/html/magento2/vendor/symfony/console/Application.php:1009
 Symfony\Component\Console\Application->doRunCommand() at /var/www/html/magento2/vendor/symfony/console/Application.php:273
 Symfony\Component\Console\Application->doRun() at /var/www/html/magento2/vendor/magento/framework/Console/Cli.php:115
 Magento\Framework\Console\Cli->doRun() at /var/www/html/magento2/vendor/symfony/console/Application.php:149
 Symfony\Component\Console\Application->run() at /var/www/html/magento2/bin/magento:23
```

Comment: Hello @chris the downgrade doesn't work for me. Any idea?

Comment: Hi @michelangelo.
You need to run "php bin/magento setup:upgrade" first before running "setup:di:compile", otherwise you are just recompiling the old Magento modules.

Comment: This is the answer.

Comment: Hi @ChrisPerver I have executed "php bin/magento setup:upgrade" first before running "setup:di:compile" but the result is the same: https://i.imgur.com/LzzgzJO.png

Comment: Just put this in your composer.json and run composer update command. 
It's not a symfony issue, it's Magento not being smart enough to resolve types correctly
`"conflict": {
"symfony/console": ">=v5.3.4||>=v4.4.27"
},`

Comment: Hi @Michelangelo. I am not sure why it is not working there. I tried working at this for hours. When I downgraded symfony/console it worked first time. Maybe you should try running the Magento cache:clear and cache:flush before trying the upgrade. Failing that, maybe try one of the other solutions on this page.

Comment: @ChrisPerver nothing to do. The problem still persist. Hi Slimshadddyyy I have tested your solution too. It doesn't work.

Comment: @Michelangelo According to a post on this page, a new version of symfony/console has been published, 4.4.29. So you could try removing any symfony/console requirements from your composer.json and rerun the composer update script. And hope it works!

Comment: Hello again, after debugging the code I have discovered that adding the conflict in the composer.json doesn't resolve the issue because when you update the project with the composer update command, Magento will be downgraded! but this situation has been useful because I have understood that the vendor pakages were not updated correctly! Infact when I have deleted the conflict row from my composer.json it has forced the update of Magento and its dependencies again and the issue is disappeared!

Answer (score 11):

A temporary fix that I have done taken backup of  vendor/symfony/console/Input/InputOption.php file and modify it.

After line 48 replace the comment as below before constructor:

```
/**
     * @param string $name
      * @param string|array|null                $shortcut The shortcuts, can be null, a string of shortcuts delimited by | or an array of shortcuts
      * @param int|null                         $mode     The option mode: One of the VALUE_* constants
      * @param string|bool|int|float|array|null $default  The default value (must be null for self::VALUE_NONE)
     *
     * @throws InvalidArgumentException If option mode is invalid or incompatible
     */
```

I basically added first parameter $name of string type.

Answer (score 2):

I faced this issue too, downgrading symfony/console works.

```
composer require symfony/console=4.4.26
```

Comment: This solution doesn't work at all.

Comment: @Michelangelo It did work for me

Comment: Same, works for me, and for a bunch of people per above answers.

Comment: This should be marked as the best answer

Comment: It is really odd! It doesn't work in my case! Why?! check this screenshot https://i.imgur.com/zBWTSFU.jpg

Answer (score 0):

Downgrading symfony/console works.

In CLI: composer require symfony/console=4.4.26

The error lies in vendor\symfony\console\Input\InputOption.php

The working code from last version, starting on line 50:

```
/**
 * @param string                    $name        The option name
 * @param string|array|null         $shortcut    The shortcuts, can be null, a string of shortcuts delimited by | or an array of shortcuts
 * @param int|null                  $mode        The option mode: One of the VALUE_* constants
 * @param string                    $description A description text
 * @param string|string[]|bool|null $default     The default value (must be null for self::VALUE_NONE)
 *
 * @throws InvalidArgumentException If option mode is invalid or incompatible
 */
```

Is now incorrect:

```
/**
 * @param string|array|null                $shortcut The shortcuts, can be null, a string of shortcuts delimited by | or an array of shortcuts
 * @param int|null                         $mode     The option mode: One of the VALUE_* constants
 * @param string|bool|int|float|array|null $default  The default value (must be null for self::VALUE_NONE)
 *
 * @throws InvalidArgumentException If option mode is invalid or incompatible
 */
```

Restoring this block works, but I recommend downgrading to last version to be safe. There is already a pull request for the newest version on github for symfony/console. This will also fix that issue.

https://github.com/symfony/console/pull/75

Answer (score 0):

Downgrading symfony/console works for me  : -

Run below command inside the given directory

```
         /var/www/html/magento2$ - my directory 

               -  composer require symfony/console=4.4.26     
               -  sudo php bin/magento setup:upgrade
```

Answer (score 0):

This was fixed by the Magento in their repo, so no need for the custom fix. No need to downgrade Symfony also.

https://github.com/symfony/console/pull/75/commits/eae76f1391034d4f8e4f8a6e7e73b3c6258d3b70