# Error during compilation after upgrade from 2.4.1 to 2.4.2

Tags: error, magento2.4.2, setup-di-compile, dicompilation

I have below error while running
php bin/magento setup:di:compile
Compilation was started.
Repositories code generation... 1/9 [==>----------------]  11% < 1 sec 105.0 MiB

Interception cache generation... 6/9 [=========>----]  66% 37 secs 454.0 MiBErrors during compilation:
Magento\Framework\Setup\Option\AbstractConfigOption
Incompatible argument type: Required type: int. Actual type: string; File:
/home/public_html/vendor/magento/framework/Setup/Option/AbstractConfigOption.php

Total Errors Count: 1

In Log.php line 92:

Error during compilation

setup:di:compile

Comment: please check error_log on root

Answer (score 1):

Downgrade symfony/console to v4.4.26.

composer require symfony/console=4.4.26

error resolved.

Answer (score 0):

this is due to the symfony/console package. Downgrading the symfony package worked for me. see this thread.

[Errors during compilation: AbstractConfigOption.php](https://magento.stackexchange.com/questions/341785/errors-during-compilation-abstractconfigoption-php)

Comment: looks like the package has since been updted. 2.4.7 symfony/console no longer throwing an error.

Answer (score 0):

use this command to compile:- php -dmemory_limit=4G bin/magento setup:di:compile