# M2.4.2 | Incompatible argument type: Required type

Tags: php, magento2.4.2

I keep getting this error after running a composer update, I have tried to isolate the problem in the old fashion manner, where I disabled all third-party  modules but still not working, which makes me think this is Magento core problem:

```
php bin/magento setup:di:compile
Compilation was started.
Interception cache generation... 6/9 [==================>---------]  66% 52 secs 418.0 MiBErrors during compilation:
        Magento\Framework\Setup\Option\AbstractConfigOption
                Incompatible argument type: Required type: int. Actual type: string; File:
vendor/magento/framework/Setup/Option/AbstractConfigOption.php

Total Errors Count: 1

In Log.php line 92:

  [Magento\Framework\Validator\Exception]
  Error during compilation
```

What is the origin of this variable?

[image]

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Apparently, it is a Symfony issue, I had a hunch about it because it was upgraded when I ran composer update, but never thought they would release something that might break Magento, lesson learned.

Please refer to this for the solution:
https://github.com/magento/magento2/issues/33595

Answer (score 0):

Others have posted some workarounds until the PR is merged.  See here: [Errors during compilation: AbstractConfigOption.php](https://magento.stackexchange.com/questions/341785/errors-during-compilation-abstractconfigoption-php)

Answer (score 0):

Please take a look, this will fix that issue: https://github.com/symfony/console/pull/75